# Puppet directory sync does not delete absent files

Tags: windows, puppet

Repeating [my question from SO.SE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52833285/4640431) here ...

I'm trying to have my configs directory (on Windows server 2016 node) to be synced from puppet master (puppet --version = 5.5.3) modules folder: I have my desired structure repeated under module/files. This:

```
file { "c:\\":
        ensure => directory,
        recurse => remote,
        source => "puppet:///modules/configs"
        }
```

works for files that exist in source dir, but does not delete files that are deleted from source (from docs I understood that it should) also I tried:

```
file { "c:\\":
        ensure => directory,
        recurse => true,
        purge => true,
        source => "puppet:///modules/configs"
        }
```

but then I get an error:

> Error: /Stage[main]/Main/Node[nodename]/File[c:]: Failed to generate additional resources using 'eval_generate': CreateF
>   ile(c:/Documents and Settings, 20000000000, 1, , 3, 210000000, 0):  Access is denied.

I was not able to find even descent source telling possible cause for the error; Access denied makes no sense as puppet agent runs with system privileges and should be able to access every path, also script should have nothing to do with c:/Documents and Settings path to my understanding.

Any help to solve this?

Comment: According to https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/PUP-4759 the issue seems to be solved.

Comment: Thanks! Not actual anymore - I don't work on that project already for more than half a year - don't even have puppet installation to test this :)

Answer (score 1):

According to https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/PUP-4759 the issue seems to be solved.